# Uploading image to backend

Tags: http, flutter, dart

I can not get image upload to my restAPI server via http package. I spend whole day looking for an answer and didn't find any. My backend require an actually image but I don't seems to manage it with http package.

```
  Future<void> createProfile(Profile profile) async {
    try {
      var request =
          new http.MultipartRequest("POST", Uri.parse(APIPath.createProfile()));
      request.fields.addAll(profile.toMap());
      request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
          'image', profile.image.path,
          contentType: MediaType('image', '*')));
      request.headers['authorization'] = "Bearer $_token";
      final response = await request.send();
      if (response.statusCode == 200) print('Uploaded!');

      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

My backend is written in node.js and was tested in postman so backend should be fine. However when I tried to upload an image from my front end it gives me error `only images allowed` which means the image doesn't get to the server(allowed image type is correct). Please any help appreciated

error triggered in Node.js

```
const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
   if (file.mimetype === 'image/png' || file.mimetype === 'image/gif' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg') {
      cb(null, true);
   } else {
      const error = new Error('Only images are allowed')
      error.statusCode = 406;
      cb(error);
   }
}
```

Comment: `request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
      'image',
      profile.image.path,
    ));`

Comment: @JohnJoe actually that was my first attempt but it failed.. same reason as above. Any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: did you print out profile.image.path?

Comment: @JohnJoe yes... the path is correct and points to the image on my iOS simulotor `/Users/delmin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F933AAC4-9E3C-4026-B525-E2D39F4704A8/data/Containers/Data/Application/5E128B17-4E86-422A-AFBA-A5C16704F397/tmp/image_picker_DC4A6180-2C2D-4E69-B25C-C53A50470213-21991-0003ED97B1116D5C.jpg`

Comment: did you tried using `await http.MultipartFile.fromPath`?

Comment: @JohnJoe yes.. I have edited my question with the code I'm using now

Comment: where is your `await request.send();` ?

Comment: @JohnJoe do you mean this one? `final response = await request.send();`

Comment: `only images allowed` is the error returned from backend?

Comment: @JohnJoe yes.. I have added the triggered code from node.js and it isn't returned from backend... actually I can not see it in my run terminal on client side but it is triggered on my back end side

Comment: is it possible print out `file.mimetype` in `node.js`?

Comment: @JohnJoe hmm good thinking `image/*`

Comment: @JohnJoe I have changed `MediaType('image', '*')` to `MediaType('image', 'jpg')` and it works. Reason why I used `'*'` was to allowed all image types from my client side to be uploaded to my backend.. So how do you allow all image types to be uploaded without specifying type then?

Comment: @JohnJoe well never mind..I'll ask in new question about it. You helped me a lot.. thanks.. Can you perhaps answer this question where you point me for that mistake so I can mark the question as answered?

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That because `contentType: MediaType('image', '*')` will resulted as `image/*`, which did not matched with the `file.mimetype` in `node.js`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 uri = Uri.parse(url);

 var request = new MultipartRequest("PUT", uri);

 var multipartFile = await MultipartFile.fromPath("package", path);

 //path = filepath 

 request.files.add(multipartFile);

 StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

 return response;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that is exactly what I have and it doesn't work. Please see updated code in my question

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26394437)